# Server side Framework vs Client side Frameworks

Tags: angularjs, django, vue.js, server-side, client-side

So I've recently been learning Django and it took me a while to understand that it was a Server side framework, I had previously only worked with Vue/AngularJS and I assumed Django was similar because of the same offers (for loops, if statements etc...).

**Relating to that note, what does Django actually offer that Vue/etc do not? Are client-side frameworks really only useful to produce SPA's?**

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic website/application requires a Server side application and/or a front end application. Angular, VueJs and other frameworks like these creates a SPA as you are aware speed up the application and provide more complex functionalities on client side rather than doing same operations on the server.

Django, Laravel, CakePHP and other frameworks deals with your data processing either storing them into database or retrieving them. Processing Images and a whole bunch of stuff on the server.

Django offers you a well maintained, structured API/Web application, the development time is very low, and you don't have to worry about the common stuff such as Sessions, Authentication, Security, etc that before frameworks were repeated every time by every one (almost).

You can further research what Django has to offer there is so much it handles for you.